# Conditional survival probability up to time $T$ given $t > s$

Tags: probability, survival, conditional-probability, continuous-data

This is a really basic question I know but for some reason I'm failing to convince myself of the right answer here.

Given a survival model that has CDF $F(t) = \mathbb{P}(\text{failure before}\ t)$

I would like to calculate $\mathbb{P}(t < T\ |\ t > s)$

Is it

1)  $\mathbb{P}(t < T\ |\ t > s) = \frac{F(T)}{1-F(s)}$

or

2) $\mathbb{P}(t < T\ |\ t > s) = \frac{F(T) - F(s)}{1-F(s)}$?

I believe it is #2 because $\mathbb{P}(t < T\ |\ t > s) = \frac{\mathbb{P}(t < T \ \cap\ t > s)}{\mathbb{P}(t > s)}$ and $\mathbb{P}(t < T \cap t > s) = F(T) - F(s)$. Is this correct?

Comment: P(T>s)=1-F(s). P(t>s) = 0 if t<=s, = 1 if t>s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the variable is continuous, i.e. no jumps in the CDF due to probability mass, the second option is the correct one, as you've also said (assuming $T>s$, otherwise the asked probability is $0$), because:
$$P(t<T|t>s)=\frac{P(s<t<T)}{P(t>s)}=\frac{F(T)-F(s)}{1-F(s)}$$
Note we're implicitly assuming that $P(t<T)=P(t\leq T)=F(T)\ \ , \ \forall\ T$ because the CDF is assumed to be continuous, therefore has no jumps and no single point has non-zero probability.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I guess the part I was really somehow missing was that `P(t < T & t > s) = P(s < t < T)`!